# Java Webservice JAX WS Cannot generate WSDL for binding "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/"

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wcf-binding

I use Java SE 7 Update 5 and I am able to import the below WSDL file with wsimport (only with -extension option). But in case of publishing the endpoint I get the following exception.
If i change the BindingType from:

```
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
```

to:

```
@BindingType(value = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/")
```

then I'm able to start the service, but I get this warning: "Generating non-standard WSDL for the specified binding"
The warning itself isn't the problem, but when I access/import the published WSDL from an external client(e.g. soapUI), then the requests are malformed and they don't work. (missing elements)

It seems there is an error within the WSDL definition.(see below)

**Exception:**

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Cannot generate WSDL for binding  "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/"
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.generateWSDL(EndpointFactory.java:421)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:198)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:179)
    at at.tac.ra.ng.bl.rainterface.webservice.WebServiceServer.startServer(WebServiceServer.java:140)
    at at.tac.ra.ng.bl.rainterface.webservice.WebServiceServer.startInterface(WebServiceServer.java:182)
    at at.tac.ra.ng.bl.rainterface.webservice.WebServiceServer$2.run(WebServiceServer.java:176)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**WSDL - File:**

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="http://system//system_EntryDataServices" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="system_EntryDataServices" targetNamespace="http://system//system_EntryDataServices">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://system//system_EntryDataServices" xmlns:SOAP_ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://system//system_EntryDataServices">

          <xsd:complexType name="handleArrivalEntryUpdate">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="UpdateEntry" nillable="true" type="tns:UpdateArrivalEntryRequest"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="UpdateArrivalEntryRequest">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="ArrivalEntry" type="tns:ArrivalData" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xsd:element name="MessageType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="ArrivalData">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Number1" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="String1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xsd:element name="String2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="handleArrivalEntryUpdateResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="ResultStatus" nillable="true" type="tns:ResultStatus"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="ResultStatus">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Type" type="tns:Type"/>
              <xsd:element name="Code" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="Message" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:simpleType name="Type">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="S"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="E"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="W"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:complexType name="handleDepartureEntryUpdate">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="UpdateEntry" nillable="true" type="tns:UpdateDepartureEntryRequest"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="UpdateDepartureEntryRequest">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="DepartureEntry" type="tns:DepartureData" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xsd:element name="MessageType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="DepartureData">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Number1" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="String1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xsd:element name="String2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="handleDepartureEntryUpdateResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="ResultStatus" nillable="true" type="tns:ResultStatus"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="handleEntryDataReload">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="EntryData" nillable="true" type="tns:EntryPlanRequest"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="EntryPlanRequest">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="ArrivalEntrys" type="tns:ArrayOfArrivalData" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xsd:element name="DepartureEntrys" type="tns:ArrayOfDepartureData" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfArrivalData">
<xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ArrayOfArrivalDataItem" type="tns:ArrivalData" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>

          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfDepartureData">
<xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ArrayOfDepartureDataItem" type="tns:DepartureData" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>

          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="handleEntryDataReloadResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="ResultStatus" nillable="true" type="tns:ResultStatus"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:element name="handleArrivalEntryUpdate" type="tns:handleArrivalEntryUpdate"/>
            <xsd:element name="handleArrivalEntryUpdateResponse" type="tns:handleArrivalEntryUpdateResponse"/>
            <xsd:element name="handleDepartureEntryUpdate" type="tns:handleDepartureEntryUpdate"/>
            <xsd:element name="handleDepartureEntryUpdateResponse" type="tns:handleDepartureEntryUpdateResponse"/>
            <xsd:element name="handleEntryDataReload" type="tns:handleEntryDataReload"/>
            <xsd:element name="handleEntryDataReloadResponse" type="tns:handleEntryDataReloadResponse"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleEntryDataReload">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:handleEntryDataReload">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleArrivalEntryUpdateResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:handleArrivalEntryUpdateResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleDepartureEntryUpdate">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:handleDepartureEntryUpdate">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleEntryDataReloadResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:handleEntryDataReloadResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleDepartureEntryUpdateResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:handleDepartureEntryUpdateResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleArrivalEntryUpdate">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:handleArrivalEntryUpdate">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="system_EntryDataServices_PortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="handleArrivalEntryUpdate">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleArrivalEntryUpdate">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleArrivalEntryUpdateResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="handleDepartureEntryUpdate">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleDepartureEntryUpdate">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleDepartureEntryUpdateResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="handleEntryDataReload">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleEntryDataReload">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:system_EntryDataServices_PortType_handleEntryDataReloadResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="system_common_adapters_ws_system_EntryDataServices_Binder" type="tns:system_EntryDataServices_PortType">
    <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="handleArrivalEntryUpdate">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="system_common_adapters_ws_system_EntryDataServices_Binder_handleArrivalEntryUpdate" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="handleDepartureEntryUpdate">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="system_common_adapters_ws_system_EntryDataServices_Binder_handleDepartureEntryUpdate" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="handleEntryDataReload">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="system_common_adapters_ws_system_EntryDataServices_Binder_handleEntryDataReload" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="system_EntryDataServices">
    <wsdl:port name="system_common_adapters_ws_system_EntryDataServices_Port" binding="tns:system_common_adapters_ws_system_EntryDataServices_Binder">
      <soap12:address location="http://testsystem/ws/system.common.adapters.ws:system_EntryDataServices"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 points that worked for me during the wsdl service generation with wsimport

1) You should create a package based on your target namespace and add (or the IDE will add -- as in my case netbeans) the SEI in that path. In your case the package would be system.system_EntryDataServices

2) The above should resolve your issue. If you are still face problems, like i did, once the wsdl is generated then you should include the xsd's reference in the application deployment package (war,ear)